# Evaluating $\int_0^u\int_0^{2u-x_1}\cdots \int_0^{ku-x_1-\cdots -x_{n-1}}dx_ndx_{n-1}\cdots dx_2dx_1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have reduced a problem to evaluating the integral $\int_0^u\int_0^{2u-x_1}\cdots \int_0^{ku-x_1-x_2-...-x_{n-1}}dx_ndx_{n-1}\cdots dx_2dx_1$.

I tried computing this for small $n=1,2,3$ but I can't seem to find any formula that I could then prove inductively. The parameter $u$ here is a real number.

Comment: i would try a change of variables $\sum _i^{n-1} x_i=y_{n-1}$

Comment: @tired Do you mean $\sum_i^kx_i=y_k$ for every $k$?

Comment: yeah, exactly the jacobian should be one. As a variant u can also try $nu-\sum _i^{n-1} x_i=y_{n-1}$ should also work out.

Comment: @tired It is one. Alright! A change of variables didn't occur to me.

Comment: @tired And how do you proceed after that?

Comment: the integral should be much nicer now..

Comment: @tired nevermind, you are right!

Comment: oh that's nice! would you like to share the result?

Comment: If I am not mistaken you arrive at $\int_0^u\int_0^{2u}...\int_0^{ku}1dy_1...d_y_n=n!u^n$

Comment: Yepp, very good! For an alternative way to think about that see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume

Comment: @tired Out of curiosity, what are the vertices of the simplex that has such an integral as volume?

Comment: this should be the   scaled standard simplex with vertices $(0,0,....,u,....,0,0)$

Comment: @tired Are you sure? In the standard simplex one does not have constraints like $x_1+x_2\le 2u$....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through that integral we are computing the $k$-dimensional Lebesgue measure  of the set given by $x_i\geq 0$ and $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n\leq nu$ for every $n\in[1,k]$. That is obviously $u^k$ times the $k$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of the set given by $x_i\geq 0$ and $x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n\leq n$ for every $n\in[1,k]$. Let $S_n = x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n$. We must have $0\leq S_n\leq n$ and $S_{n+1}\geq S_n$. So we may choose at random (with respect to a uniform distribution) $k$ points from the interval $[0,k]$ and, assuming such points are $P_1\leq P_2\leq\ldots\leq P_k$, compute the probability $\mathbb{P}_k$ that such points fulfill $P_n\leq n$ for every $n\in[1,k]$. $\mathbb{P}_k$ can be computed by induction, by computing first what is the probability that the maximum of $n$ independent, uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$, random variables lies in $\left[1-\frac{1}{n},1\right]$. That probability is $1-\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$.

At last we have:

> $$ \int_{0}^{u}\int_{0}^{2u-x_1}\cdots\int_{0}^{nu-x_1-\ldots-x_{n-1}}dx_n\,dx_{n-1}\ldots dx_1 = u^n \frac{(n+1)^n}{(n+1)!}.$$

That numbers arise in the Taylor series of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: that's an interesting way to calculate this integral. Alternativly one could also think about the volume of an $n$ simplex

Comment: The calculation does not check out for $n=2$ ! The result should be $3t^2/2$.

Comment: @Sergei: where that $t$ comes from?

Comment: Sorry. I meant $3u^2/2$

Comment: @Sergei: you are right, I made a mistake in the previous computations, but the final result now is right, I checked it numerically, too.

Comment: Yes. It checks out with some other data I have.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, really elegant proof!